# Balance 3 phase inverter output

Tags: inverter, three-phase, solar-energy

I have a 6kw pv solar system with a 3 phase inverter which splits the generated electricity equally across the 3 phases.  I can't resell the excess capacity back so I want to make the most use of the power.  Is there a product that would dynamically rebalance the excess to the circuit that needs it. For example my electric car charges on one phase so that could take a big chunk of the 6kw.  I know I could go down the battery route but for now that is too expensive.

Comment: Search for "active power filters" & co. Part of their job is to balance the currents such that the source sees a ballanced and linear load. This could even be a part of the inverter (e.g. PWM controlled inverter/PFC).

Comment: I've searched but not found anything that appears to divert power from one phase to another.

Comment: Rotary converter with enough inertia would help to balance the loads on all three phases.

Answer (score 2):

You need a strategy that prioritizes the loads. If you decide that certain loads should be allowed to operate when they turn on, you could design a system that allows that but only allows the car to charge at a rate dictated by the available power. Most other loads would need to be either on or off as the available power dictates. You don't need a product that re-balances the loads, you needs a control system that monitors the power usage and the available power. The system could provide a display that notifies you what loads you can connect or prevents certain loads from operating. It must also set the charging rate for the car. The car charger must be capable of operating under the command of the control system. Some of the pieces may be available as products. The control unit might be a general-purpose programmable unit.

Comment: I've already got a device that monitors the grid supply and inverter output for each phase and so can easily see the load.  The car charger I can put on an actuator so it only charges when I have excess energy.  The problem is the excess energy will be on 2 of the phases which are not connected to the car.

Comment: If you have just one DC source that is making 3-phase AC, you can probably load the phases unequally without causing too much difficulty.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I agree that an APF may be overkill, but maybe bypassing the inverter might be better idea, and it will improve the overall efficiency. If possible.